# How to know user install app from apple store via invite link

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using JunoWallet+ for iPhone

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/junowallet+tv/id597084729?mt=8

When I invite friends to use this app via email, my friends will receive an email with a link which used to install app from apple store. And when app was installed via this link, I will receive a gift code.

How to know if user install app from apple store via the invite link?

Comment: Kinadish off-topic, but how the hell does stuff like that even get on the AppStore?! And more absurdly, why do people us it?!

Comment: I really want do it for my app, you can try JunoWallet+ to understand. Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing to do with client in your case .. its a server thing to be implemented.. ask you server guys to implement web services for it.

Comment: @JustSid I guess that JunoWallet is nothing to do with the user. It's an example of something they want to implement. Linking a bad app does not make it a bad question worthy of a down vote.

Comment: @Fogmeister For the record, I wasn't the one down voting! I just posted the comment and that was that.

Comment: @JustSid ok, no worries, sorry for assuming that. It is a good point though. That Juno Wallet app does look horrendous.

Answer (score 3):

It's nothing to do with the install of the app or the download from the AppStore.

When you send an invite to a "friend" then the app will send the email address up to its server and the server will create a record something like...

```
Invite
------
FromUser
ToEmailAddress
```

Then when your friend receives the email address they install the app and sign up using their email address.

At which point the server will say "Hey, there is an invite associated with this email address. Lets give the person who invited them some credit."

In short, it's all server side stuff.

Comment: Thank Fogmeister. I tried a different email to sign up but still get a same result. I think server can store a param of device(eg, UDID) when  I open invite link, and use it to compare when user active app from device. May be?

Comment: You may be right. In any case though, it is a server side thing. At some point in the process they capture your info (whether it is your email address, device id, etc...) then when you sign up they can associate that info with your account.

Comment: @Tuyenp ?? any particular reason for removing the accepted tick?